# Constant derivative of a function implies is an affine map.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the next:

Let $f :\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable, where $\Omega$ is an open
connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $D_{f}(x)$ is constant on $\Omega$, that is,$D_{f}(x) = T$
for all $x\in\Omega.$ Show that $f$ is the restriction to $\Omega$ of an affine transformation.

I was trying to prove that the set $A=\{x\in\Omega: f(x) = f(a) + T(x-a)\},$ where $a\in\Omega$ is fixed, is an open and closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ then for connected of $\Omega$ implies $\Omega = A$ and the proposition is true, but it seems quite hard to prove that; I was thinking about the definition of differentaiblity of $f$ in $a,$ however the best that we get of such definition is an inequality.

I saw a proof of this using gradient theorem but I do not know yet integration; this proposition appears in the section of differential calculus only, hence it must be possible prove it without integration.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering $f-T$ we can reduce the proof to the case when $D_f(x)=0$ for all $x$. (In this case we prove that $f$ is a constant $c$. In general we get $f(x)=c+Tx$).

Let $x \in \Omega$ and consider a disk $B(x,r) $ contained in $\Omega$. Define $g$ on $[0,1]$ by $g(t)=f(tx+(1-t)y)$. Using Chain Rule show that $g'(t)=0$ for all $t$. It follows that $g$ is constant. Hence $f(x)=g(1)=g(0)=f(y)$. We have proved that each point of $\Omega$ has neighborhood in which $f$ is a constant. Now prove that for any fixed $x_0 \in \Omega$ $\{x \in \Omega: f(x)=f(x_0)\}$ is open and closed in $\Omega$ to finish the proof (using connectedness).

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy. Considering the reduction $f-T$ left the case when derivative is zero and then the rest is easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Proving that $A$ is open and closed is a good idea.

The fact that it is closed is trivial as $A$ is the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under the continuous map $g(x)=f(x)-f(a)-T(x-a)$. All linear maps are continuous in a finite dimensional space.

To prove that is is open, take $b \in A$ and prove that   $A$ contains a small open ball centered on $b$. For this use Mean Value Theorem on line segments.

Comment: Of course! I forgot completly that $T$ is continuous because of the finite dimensional space. Many thanks.